# Ternary operator why c++ gives rvalue but lvalue in c

Tags: c++, c, ternary-operator

```
int a,b;
...
((a>b) ? a : b) = value ;
```

This is error in c.

> **lvalue required** for assigning value.

But This works fine in c++.

Why not in c and in c++? whats the difference? whats happening? i know that it returns lvalue in c thats why error. fine. But why it is so in c and c++ allowed it by returning rvalue?

Comment: Take a loot at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator