# Operator 'sizeof' with conditional (ternary) expression

Tags: c, sizeof, conditional-operator

I have a hard time understanding `sizeof`'s behaviour when given a ternary expression.

```c
#define STRING "a string"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a = sizeof(argc > 1 ? STRING : "");

  int b = sizeof(STRING);
  int c = sizeof("");

  printf("%d\n" "%d\n" "%d\n", a, b, c);

  return 0;
}
```

In this example (tested with gcc 4.4.3 and 4.7.2, compiled with `-std=c99`), b is 9 (8 characters + implicit `'\0'`), c is 1 (implicit `'\0'`). a, for some reason, is **4**.

I would expect a to be either 9 or 1, based on whether argc is greater than 1. I thought maybe the string literals get converted to pointers before being passed to `sizeof`, causing `sizeof(char*)` to be 4.

I tried replacing `STRING` and `""` by char arrays...

```c
char x[] = "";
char y[] = "a string";
int a = sizeof(argc > 1 ? x : y);
```

... but I got the same results (a=4, b=9, c=1).

Then I tried to dive into the [C99 spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), but I did not find any obvious explanation in it. Out of curiosity I also tried changing changing x and y to other types:

- `char` and `long long int`: a becomes 8
- both `short` or both `char`: a becomes 4

So there's definitely some sort of conversion going on, but I struggle to find any official explanation. I can sort of imagine that this would happen with arithmetic types (I'm vaguely aware there's plenty of promotions going on when those are involved), but I don't see why **a string literal returned by a ternary expression would be converted to something of size 4**.

NB: on this machine `sizeof(int) == sizeof(foo*) == 4`.

### Follow-up

Thanks for the pointers guys. Understanding how `sizeof` and `?:` work actually led me to try a few more type mashups and see how the compiler reacted. I'm editing them in for completeness' sake:

```c
foo* x = NULL; /* or foo x[] = {} */
int  y = 0;    /* or any integer type */

int a = sizeof(argc > 1 ? x : y);
```

Yields `warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression [enabled by default]`, and `a == sizeof(foo*)`.

With `foo x[], bar y[]`, `foo* x, bar* y` or `foo* x, bar y[]`, the warning becomes `pointer type mismatch`. No warning when using a `void*`.

```c
float x = 0; /* or any floating-point type */
int   y = 0; /* or any integer type */

int a = sizeof(argc > 1 ? x : y);
```

Yields no warning, and `a == sizeof(x)` (that is, the floating-point type).

```c
float x = 0;    /* or any floating-point type */
foo*  y = NULL; /* or foo y[] = {} */

int a = sizeof(argc > 1 ? x : y);
```

Yields `error: type mismatch in conditional expression`.

If I ever read the spec completely I'll make sure to edit this question to point to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to understand *expressions*, which are the core component of the language.

Every expression has a *type*. For an expression `e`, `sizeof e` is the size of the type of the value of the expression `e`.

The expression `a ? b : c` has a type. The type is the *common type* of the two operand expressions `b` and `c`.

In your example, the common type of `char[9]` and `char[1]` is `char *` (both array-valued expressions decay to a pointer to the first element). (In C++, the rules for string literals are different and there is a `const` everywhere.)

Comment: Could you point to the parts of the spec that say 1) "the type of expression `a?b:c` is the common type of `b` and `c`" 2) "the common type of two arrays is a pointer" ?

This does seem logical, but I'd really like to actually see that written in some official form.

Comment: @Peniblec This is already covered on SO @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: Okay, 6.5.15 explains the "conversion" part (§6 indeed says "if both 2nd and 3rd operands are pointers then expression has type pointer"), but does not mention arrays. I *think* 6.3.2.1, §3 is what I'm after? ("expression of type "array of T" is converted to "pointer to T" except when given to sizeof, &, or when it's a string literal used to initialize an array")

Comment: @Peniblec: Yes, they both decay to `char *` (not to `const char *`, btw, although they should IMO). You cannot build the composite type of two non-variable arrays both with a different length given (but that's irrelevant here, an array as operand of `?:` decays to a pointer).

Comment: @mafso: Ah, of course, in C it's `char *`. In C++ it's `const char *` as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, yes, didn't think of C++, where it's indeed `const char *`… But I still think, your answer is a little misleading. I don't know, if “common type” is a C++ term, but for C, there is _compatible type_ and if two types are compatible, they have a _composite type_. `char [9]` and `char [1]` are incompatible, so there is no composite type. The expression is valid only because they both decay to `char *` before the types are compared (and `char *` is compatible to `char *`). Your answer could lead to the impression, that `sizeof(*(argc>1 ? &STRING, &""))` would be valid, which it isn't.

Comment: You make it sound as if the pointer decay happens after the determination of a common type, but it happens before. You could have said “the common type of char[9] and char[9] is char*”, and it would have been equally misleading.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: That's because I was originally thinking of C++, where `foo() ? "Hello" : "World"` does indeed have type `char const [6]`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to understand that `sizeof` is entirely a **compile-time** operator.
With [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) it could return a variable expression, otherwise it is a compile-time constant.

What matters is the type of its argument.

So in `sizeof(argc > 1 ? STRING : "")`  the condition is *not* evaluated. The type of the argument is decayed to `const char*`. And on your machine, it is 4.

You should code instead `(argc > 1)?sizeof(STRING):1`

Since `STRING` is macro-expanded to the `"a string"` literal, `sizeof(STRING)` is 9, nearly as if you have declared

```
const char STRING[] = {'a',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};
```

Comment: Not quite always: Try `sizeof` with a variably modified type.

Comment: Thanks, I guess in my head the compiler would just reword that to `if (argc > 1) sizeof STRING; else sizeof ""`. Didn't realize `?:` would be resolved to a type at compile-time. Also thanks for suggesting an alternative.

Comment: @usr: No, `STRING` is macro-expanded to `"a string"` so `sizeof(STRING)` is 9.

Answer (score 2):

Both `STRING` and `""` are array objects of types `char[9]` and `char[1]` respectively. In C language, when array objects are used in expressions, they get implicitly converted (decay) to *pointer* types in almost all contexts, with few well-known specific exceptions.

One of such exceptions is `sizeof` operator. When you use an array object as an immediate operand of `sizeof` that array object does not decay to pointer type, and you get the size of the entire array in bytes as result. This is why `sizeof(STRING)` is equivalent to `sizeof(char[9])` and evaluates to `9`. And `sizeof("")` is equivalent to `sizeof(char[1])` and evaluates to `1`.

But when you use array objects as operands of `?:` operator, the context is no longer exceptional. In context of `?:` operator arrays immediately decay to pointers. This means that your `sizeof(argc > 1 ? STRING : "")` is equivalent to `sizeof(argc > 1 ? (char *) STRING : (char *) "")`, and in turn equivalent to `sizeof(char *)`. This evaluates to pointer size on your platform, which just happens to be `4`.

Comment: This nicely wraps everything I learned from reading the spec after Kerrek SB's answer! May I suggest including references when making such assertions? I think it would add educational value (as in, "This document is not a huge behemoth full of gibberish only language designers can hope to understand; here are the sections relevant to your problem. As you can see, it's plain English and describes precisely the mechanisms responsible for what you observed"). Give man a fish, and all that :)

NB: I already dug up some paragraphs I thought were relevant, cf. comments below Kerrek SB's answer.