# Overloaded function evaluated with ternary

Tags: c++

I have an overloaded function which can take two argument types : `int` and `double`. When I evaluate it with a ternary which can return either an `int` or a `double`, it always uses the `double` version. Why is that?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int a)
{
    cout << "int" << endl;
}

void f(double a)
{
    cout << "double" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    f(a=="int" ? 3 : 3.14159);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8535301/1729885).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return type of '?:' (ternary conditional operator)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ternary operator always do type promotion (into single type). So if one result is int and another is double, the result of ? operartor will always be double.