# C++14: deduced (auto) return types from constexpr with ternary expressions

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, c++14, constexpr

I am experimenting with constexpr functions in C++14. The following code, which computes the factorial works as expected:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto fact(T a) {
    if(a==1)
        return 1;
    return a*fact(a-1);
}

int main(void) {
    static_assert(fact(3)==6,  "fact doesn't work");
}
```

when it is compiled as follows with clang:

```
> clang++ --version
clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
> clang++ -std=c++14 constexpr.cpp
```

However, when I change the `fact` definition to use the ternary `?` operator:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto fact(T a) {
    return a==1 ? 1 : a*fact(a-1);
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
> clang++ -std=c++14 constexpr.cpp
constexpr.cpp:12:31: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of
      256
    return a==T(1) ? T(1) : a*fact(a-1);
        ... snip ...
constexpr.cpp:16:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fact<int>'
      requested here
    static_assert(fact(3)==6,  "fact doesn't work");
```

The problem is fixed if I explicitly state the return type T (instead of using auto to deduce the return type)

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T fact(T a) {
    return a==1 ? 1 : a*fact(a-1);
}
```

If I remove the template parameter, the pattern is repeated (the ternary version fails, and the `if` version works)

```
// this works just fine
constexpr auto fact(int a) {
    if(a==1)
        return 1;
    return a*fact(a-1);
}
```

whereas this fails

```
constexpr auto fact(int a) {
    return a==1 ? 1 : a*fact(a-1);
}
```

with the following error

```
> clang++ -std=c++14 constexpr.cpp
constexpr.cpp:16:25: error: function 'fact' with deduced return type cannot be used before it
      is defined
    return a==1 ? 1 : a*fact(a-1);
                        ^
constexpr.cpp:15:16: note: 'fact' declared here
constexpr auto fact(int a) {
               ^
constexpr.cpp:20:26: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'int')
    static_assert(fact(3)==6,  "fact doesn't work");
                  ~~~~~~~^ ~
2 errors generated.
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The resulting type from evaluating a ternary expression is the [common type of its second and third arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8535244/241631).

By having the compiler deduce the return type, you force it to evaluate both of these arguments to the ternary expression. This means that the recursion doesn't end even when the terminating condition is reached, because when `a==1`, to figure out the return type of `fact(0)` the compiler must continue evaluating further recursive calls to `fact`, and endless recursion ensues.

By stating the return type, `fact(0)` does not need to be evaluated when `a==1`, and the recursion is able to terminate.

---

As for the case with the two `return` statements, the relevant standard clause is —

(from N4296) *§7.1.6.4/9* **[dcl.spec.auto]**

> If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder type has multiple return statements, **the return type is deduced for each return statement**. If the type deduced is not the same in each deduction, the program is ill-formed.

In your example, in the call to `fact<int>(1)`, the return type deduced from the first `return` statement is `int`, so the return type of `fact<int>(0)` in the second `return` statement cannot be anything but `int` as well. This means the compiler does not need to evaluate the body of `fact<int>(0)` and the recursion can terminate.

Indeed, if you force evaluation of the call to `fact` in the second `return` statement as well, for instance by changing the first example so that `T` is a non-type template argument

```
template <unsigned T>
constexpr auto fact() {
    if(T==1)
        return 1;
    return T*fact<T-1>();
}
```

clang does fail with the error

> fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 256

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e98a4e6c3e1574e)

Comment: The if version has two return statements. Does the compiler use/standard specify some sort of lazy evaulation, where it only considers the return statement in the if block when a==1? Otherwise we would have the same problem with both versions.

Comment: Thanks @Praetorian. I can look it up myself (though I am not much of a language lawyer).

Comment: @Praetorian It isn't the opposite of what you claimed earlier. The return type is deduced for each return statement, but once it's deduced for *any* return statement, the return type is known and can be used as part of the deduction of later return statements. The reason your example with `template <unsigned T>` fails is because `fact<T>`'s return type being known says nothing about `fact<T-1>`'s return type, but it's `fact<int>` that calls `fact<int>` in the OP's code.