# sizeof of the conditional operator's value ?:

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()  
{ int x = 1;    
short int i = 2;   
float f = 3; 
  if(sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float))    
  printf("float\n");  
  else if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(short int))     
  printf("short int\n");    
}
```

Here the expression `((x == 2) ? f : i)` evaluates to `i` which is of type short int.. size of short int =2 whereas sizeof float is 4 byts.output should be "short int" but i m getting output "float"

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator

Answer (score 6):

> Here the expression ((x == 2) ? f : i) evaluates to i which is of type short int

This is not how *usual arithmetic conversions* work in C. The second and third operands of `? :` are first converted to a common type, and that type is the type of the result of the expression. And also that type will not in any case be smaller than `int`, because of promotions.

This is all described in clause **6.3.1 Arithmetic operands** of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf), which is slightly too long to cite here.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is a compile-time operator, so it cannot evaluate `x==2`. It evaluates the *type* of the ternary expression, which in this case is `float`, via a conversion to a common type (the second and third operands of the ternary expression must be of the same type, and the `int` gets converted to `float`.)