# What is the type of a ternary operator expression in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, expression, ternary-operator

When given an expression of the form

```
a ? b : c
```

what is its type? Can the types of `b` and `c` differ and the expression still be valid? If so, what are the rules on what the type of the expression is. What rules are there for rvalue- and lvalue-ness?

Comment: I don't know if it is true in general, but [Microsoft has an MSDN article detailing the rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx)

Comment: The scope of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator is much narrower than mine. Even though it is a good link, the answers there, do not fully answer my question.

Comment: The answers do indeed fully answer your question. Several yards of the standard are quoted.

Comment: @EJP None of them have a quote from the C++11 standard though. The yards of quotes are from N1905, a 2005 working draft. That said, [expr.cond] is 1.5 pages long, so I'm not really inclined to quote it again...

Comment: @T.C. Did it change in C++11?

Comment: @EJP Yes, that section changed in the last 10 years.