# function pointer definition on ternary operator

Tags: c++, pointers

When I define a function pointer in C++ using the ternary operator I get the compiler error `overloaded function with no contextual type information`.
I'm confused. Could someone explain me the reason of this behavior?

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

const char *my_strstr1 (const char *__haystack, const char *__needle) {
    std::cout << "my_strstr" << std::endl;
    return strstr(__haystack, __needle);
}

const char *my_strstr2 (const char *__haystack, const char *__needle) {
    std::cout << "my_strstr2" << std::endl;
    return strstr(__haystack, __needle);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "argc:" << argc << std::endl;

    //ok
    // const char* (*StrStr)(const char*, const char*) = strstr;
    // const char* (*StrStr)(const char*, const char*) = (argc > 1) ? my_strstr2 : my_strstr1;

    // error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
    const char* (*StrStr)(const char*, const char*) = (argc > 1) ? my_strstr1 : strstr;

    StrStr("helloworld", "h");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you wish to write: (argc > 1) ? my_strstr1 : my_strstr2;

Comment: @user3286661 No, OP wants to use the standard library `strstr`.

Comment: Then prepend it with std::

Comment: It's a C legacy function, no need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one version of `strstr` function. So compiler don't know which one should be used so you have to tell the compiler which one you want:

```
const char* (*StrStr)(const char*, const char*) = (argc > 1) ? my_strstr1 : (const char* (*)(const char*, const char*))strstr;
```

You can take a look to similar SO question: [Return type of '?:' (ternary conditional operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator).

And also section 5.16 in [Working draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)

Comment: then why this code knows how to choose the right version?
    //ok
    // const char* (*StrStr)(const char*, const char*) = strstr;

Comment: Assigment operator knows, ternary operator don't.

Comment: can u explain more or share a link about this?
It's the 1st time I heard about this since using C++. 3q.

Answer (score 1):

The overload of [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) defined in `string.h` is:

```
char *strstr( const char* str, const char* substr );
```

And in `<cstring>` there are two [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr)s:

```
const char* strstr( const char* str, const char* target );
      char* strstr(       char* str, const char* target );
```

Either way, that doesn't match your other function. The former has the wrong return type, and the latter has two overloads and you're using it in a context that doesn't allow for that.

The simplest approach is just to "fix" which `strstr` you want with a lambda and just use that:

```
using F = const char*(*)(const char*, const char*);
F std_version = [](const char* s, const char* t) -> const char* {
    return strstr(s, t);
};

F StrStr = (argc > 1) ? my_strstr1 : std_version ;
```

Comment: Won't this clash because `std` is a namespace?

Comment: I think that does match, bcz the code could be compiled correctly.
    //ok
    // const char* (*StrStr)(const char*, const char*) = strstr;

Comment: @GillBates Nope. But changed it anyway.