# Difference on address of const reference to ternary operator between clang and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, ternary-operator, clang++

I have a vague idea of what's going on here... and it has to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator) but I'm wondering why clang++ and g++ handle this differently. Where is the undefined behaviour arround here? Note: this has nothing to do with templates - I just use them to make the example more compact. It's all about the type of `whatever`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void test()
{
    T whatever = 'c';


    const char a = 'a';

    std::cout << "begin: " << (void*)&a << std::endl;

    const char & me = (true ? a : whatever);

    std::cout << "ref:   " << (void*)&me << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{

    test<const char>();
    test<char>();

    return 0;
}
```

gcc output (tested up to 4.9.3):

```
begin: 0x7fffe504201f
ref:   0x7fffe504201f
begin: 0x7fffe504201e
ref:   0x7fffe504201f
```

clang 3.7.0 output:

```
begin: 0x7ffed7b6bb97
ref:   0x7ffed7b6bb97
begin: 0x7ffed7b6bb97
ref:   0x7ffed7b6bb97
```

Comment: Probably reducable to `char a; const char b; const char& r = (true?a:b); std::cout << (&a==&r);`

Comment: Reproduced on gcc 4.9.2, failed to on 5.3.0 and 6.1

Comment: Failed to reproduce on gcc 6.2.1.

Comment: @Mooing Duck , correct. Updated answer

Comment: @neverlastn so where is the undefined behavior now?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: why do you think there is undefined behaviour?

Comment: Looks like gcc 4.9.2 generates temporary of type `char` from `a` to create common type with the third argument. This seem to be incorrect, but I do not see undefined behavior here.

Comment: So it's a gcc bug, not an undefined behaviour, right? Someone also told me that gcc's behaviour is OK for C++03 but not in C++11 because the spec changed in between

Comment: @neverlastn even if it is a bug you should not notice the difference unless you do something ugly.

Comment: @Slava - I have some innocent-looking but potentially dangerous examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167231/is-it-safe-to-create-a-const-reference-to-result-of-ternary-operator-in-c).

Comment: I recommend staying away from the gcc 4.9.x series.  It has a lot of problems including very spotty c++11 support and some versions can generate bad asm.  Also, be wary of people who work on gcc giving biased opinions on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer from [this other question from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167231/is-it-safe-to-create-a-const-reference-to-result-of-ternary-operator-in-c) covers your cases in detail.  I'll avoid repeating myself and just summarize.

If we factor out the templates you have two cases. Case 1:

```
const char whatever = 'c';
const char a = 'a';
const char & me = (true ? a : whatever);
```

The second and third operands of the conditional operator are both "lvalue of type `const char`", so the result is "lvalue of type `const char`" designating the selected operand.  Finally, `const char &` binds directly to "lvalue of type `const char`", so `&me` == `&a`.

For case 2:

```
char whatever = 'c';
const char a = 'a';
const char & me = (true ? a : whatever);
```

The second and third operand are "lvalue of type `char`" and "lvalue of type `const char`". The result of this is "lvalue of type `const char`" designating the selected operand. As before, `const char &me` binds directly to an lvalue of type `const char`, so `&me == &a`.

If a compiler prints different addresses for `me` and `a` in either case, it is a compiler bug.