# auto Function with if Statement won't return a value

Tags: c++

I made a template and an ***auto*** function that compare 2 values and return the smallest one.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Template with a value returning function: PrintSmaller
template <typename T, typename U>
auto PrintSmaller(T NumOne, U NumTwo) {
    if (NumOne > NumTwo) {
        return NumTwo;
    }
    else {
        return NumOne;
    }
}

int main() {

    int iA = 345;
    float fB = 23.4243;

    cout << PrintSmaller(iA, fB) << endl;
    cout << PrintSmaller(fB, iA) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it won't compile, I get this error on VS 2015:
*Error  C3487   'int': all return expressions must deduce to the same type: previously it was 'float'*

However, if I delete the ***if*** statement and write the function ***PrintSmaller*** like this it works with no problems :

```
auto PrintSmaller(T NumOne, U NumTwo) {
return (NumOne < NumTwo ? NumOne : NumTwo);
}
```

What is the difference ? and why the first code won't compile ?
Thank you.

Comment: The ternary statement is probably inducing an implicit conversion. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8535301/1460794) might be related.

Comment: Are you compiling with -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function can only have a single `return` type. Using `return` type deduction means that it will be deduced based on the type of the expression in the *first* `return` statement the parser sees. If later `return` statements do not return expressions of the same type, then the function is considered to be self-contradictory and thus ill-formed.

In the second case, the `?:` determines the type of the expression based on a common type determined based on the second and third sub-expressions. The two sub-expressions will be converted to this common type.

That's different from how `return` type deduction works. If you intend for your first case to work, then you need to *explicitly* convert the returned value to the desired return type.

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked this question with the c++11 marker, I suppose you are using C++11. Unfortunately, the C++11 standard states that auto-type deduction (also for lambdas) is limited to a single statement.

As the `?:` operator is an expression instead of a statement, this will work while the `if-else` is a statement and doesn't meet the requirements.

If you would compile this code with the C++14 standard, you will see that it should compile both cases as this limitation was removed.

Comment: sorry my bad, I'm actually working on VS 2015, I assume it uses latest standard c++14

Answer (score 0):

Until yesterday (2017-12-06) this was not compiling under MSVC. But after VS 15.5 update it does.

```
    auto msvc_does_compile = [](auto _string)
     {
      using string_type = decltype(_string);
      return std::vector<string_type>{};
     };
   /*
    OK since VS 2017 15.5 update
   auto vec1 = msvc_does_compile( std::string{} );
   */
```

Adding explicit return type will choke MSVC , but not gcc/clang as usual:

```
auto msvc_does_not_compile = [](auto _string)
    // explicit return type makes msvc not to compile
    -> std::vector< decltype(_string) >
  {
    using string_type = decltype(_string);
    return std::vector<string_type>{};
  };
```

And something of the same but simpler will be stopped even at the IDE stage:

```
    auto msvc_ide_does_not_allow = []( bool wide )
    {
       if (wide)
        return std::vector<std::string>();

        return std::vector<std::wstring>();
    };
```

Yes, again that troublesome pair gcc/clang has no problems with the above. Try which ever online ide you prefer to convince yourself...