# Why type cast failed only in this sentence?

Tags: c++, casting

I run into this when I tried to print a hexadecimal number by this sentence:

```
cout << (a > 9 ? (char)('A' + a - 10) : a);
```

However, when `a > 9`, it prints an integar, not a char.
but

```
cout << (char)('A' + a - 10);
```

worked well.
Why things go like that? How can I solve it?
Thanks for any hint.

Comment: It looks like `a`  is declared as `int`. Why don't you show the declaration of `a`?

Answer (score 4):

The type of an expression is determined at compile time, it can't depend on runtime conditions. When the two resulting expressions in a conditional (aka tertiary) expression are different, they have to be converted to a common type, and this is the type of the expression as a whole. See [Return type of '?:' (ternary conditional operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for the details.

In your case, `a` is presumably `int`, and `(char)('A' + a - 10)` is `char`, so the common type is `int`, so `cout` uses its method for printing `int` rather than `char`.

Instead of a tertiary, use an ordinary `if`:

```
if (a > 9) {
    cout << static_cast<char>('A' + a - 10);
} else {
    cout << a;
}
```

Or cast to `char` *after* doing the conditional.

```
cout << static_cast<char>(a > 9 ? ('A' + a - 10) : ('0' + a));
```

Comment: A possibly better conversion would be `cout << (char)(a > 9 ? 'A' + a -10 : '0' + a)`.      In other words, allow the `?:` operator to consistently give a result of type `int`, and convert that to `char`.

Comment: Better use a `static_cast` than a C style cast, so as to not teach Bad Programming Habits™. Or if you value the conciseness of a C style cast, express it in C++ syntax like `char( expr )`, which is both shorter and less visually noisy.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`cout << (char)(a > 9 ? ('A' + a - 10) : a + '0');`

Comment: That will print control characters instead of single digits. `(char) 3` is `'\3'`.

Comment: @Barmar: fixed that.

Comment: @Tanveer: better use a `static_cast` than a C style cast, so as to not teach Bad Programming Habits™. Or if you value the conciseness of a C style cast, express it in C++ syntax like `char( expr )`.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.