# Why does the following code not result in moving the object instead of copying?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

class A
{
public:
   A() { std::cout << "a ctor\n"; }
   A(const A&) { std::cout << "a copy ctor\n"; }
   A(A&&) { std::cout << "a move ctor\n"; }
};

A f(int i)
{
   A a1;
   return i != 0 ? a1 : A{};
}

int main()
{
   srand(time(0));
   f(rand());
   return 0;
}
```

**The output is:**

> a ctor
>
> a copy ctor

I would expect that **a1** in **f()** will be moved not copied.
If I change **f()** just a little bit, it's not a copy anymore but a move:

```
A f(int i)
{
   A a1;
   if (i != 0)
   {
      return a1;
   }
   return A{};
}
```

**The output is:**

> a ctor
>
> a move ctor

Could you explain me how does this work?
GCC 9.3.0

(edit: added random number to prevent RVO)

Comment: What compiler etc? [GCC 9.2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Of983X2o8jy8RsNO) gives me double ctor, that's all.

Comment: Is this a typo? I get `a ctor
a copy ctor` with `f(4)` but `a ctor
a ctor` with `f(5)`. The same in the second example. `f(5)` gives `a ctor
a ctor` and `f(4)` gives `a ctor
a move ctor`

Comment: I had an older compiler which did not perform RVO on the original code (that's why you saw "a ctor a ctor" output), so I've updated it with random number generation to prevent RVO.

Comment: all of your constructors has side effects with the cout stuff. cout is of course not movable and not copyable.

Comment: What kind of side effects do you mean exactly? The class does not have cout as a member, it only uses it. I'm not seeing how cout is interfering the movability of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference you're seeing is due to the use of the **ternary/conditional operator**. The ternary operator determines a *common type* and *value category* for its second and third operands, and that is determined at compile time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator).

In your case:

```
return i != 0 ? a1 : A{};
```

the common type is `A` and the common value category is prvalue since `A{}` is an prvalue. However, `a1` is an lvalue and a prvalue temporary copy of it will have to be made in the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. This explains why you see the copy constructor invoked when the condition is true: a copy of `a1` is made to convert it to an prvalue. The prvalue is copy elided by your compiler.

In the second example, where you have an `if` statement, these rules don't apply as in the case of the ternary operator. So no copy constructor invoked here.

---

To address your comment about a conditional statement with lvalue for the second and third operands, according to the [rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) of copy elision it is allowed if:

> In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile
> object with automatic storage duration, which isn't a function
> parameter or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the same class
> type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. This
> variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value
> optimization".

A conditional statement like

```
return i != 0 ? a1 : a1;
```

where the second and third operands are lvalues, does not fulfill this criteria. The expression is a conditional, not the name of an automatic object. Hence no copy elision and the copy constructor is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Actually what you wrote made sense to me, but I've tried the following:
`return i != 0 ? a1 : a1;`
In this case I would think the common value category is lvalue since a1 is an lvalue, but again I see copy constructor called.
However, if I explicitly make it into an rvalue reference then move constructor is invoked:
`return i != ? std::move(a1) : a1;`
I'm still confused.

Comment: @PeresztegiPéter See my update. Hope this answers your question.