# The result of an operator that takes an lvalue operand is an lvalue denoting that lvalue operand?

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

Reading through the Bjarne's CPP book I've encountered such a statement: "Where logically feasible, the result of an operator that takes an lvalue operand is an lvalue denoting that lvalue operand", and I really can't wrap my head around it. These are the examples included with this statement:

```cpp
void f(int x, int y)
{
    int j = x = y; // the value of x=y is the value of x after the assignment
    int∗ p = &++x; // p points to x
    int∗ q = &(x++); // error : x++ is not an lvalue (it is not the value stored in x)
    int∗ p2 = &(x>y?x:y); // address of the int with the larger value
    int& r = (x<y)?x:1; // error : 1 is not an lvalue
}
```

Code itself makes sense to me, but it makes sense from my personal understanding of how these operators work. But I can't really apply the statement here, for example for the first line. OK, `=` is an operator which can take both lvalue and rvalue operands (and from my understanding lvalue is implicitly converted to rvalue in this case) , then the result of `x = y` is an lvalue denoting `y`? If I follow this correctly, then I could write `int* j = x = y`, but this would be a compile-time error, as the result of `x = y` is clearly an rvalue. So I am really confused here.

Can anyone clarify what is this statement is semantically about and how it relates to the given examples step by step?

Comment: The result of `x = y` is an lvaule denoting `x` (which contains the value from `y`)

Comment: `x = y` is an integer value, you can't assign it to a pointer, but `int * i = &(x = y)` works

Comment: @AlexLarionov if the result of the assignment is an integer then the pointer assignment would not work as that requires an lvaule.

Comment: @RichardCritten well I understand now my mistake in wording, thanks

Comment: @RichardCritten if it would be an lvalue then it would be possible to write `int* a = b = c;` but it is not, right?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas that makes sense because `&` can be viewed here as lvalue obtaining by brute force (there is a shadow variable under the hood that contains the result of `x = y` if I am not mistaken), but it doesn't quite match the statement I faced in the book...

Comment: Well, it turns out it's possible to write `int& j = x = y;`, so it seems that yeah, `=` operator really returns an lvalue denoting the `x` after the assignment was made! And with this the statement itself starts to make sense.  Would someone like to post an answer here so I'll make it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `x = y` returns lvalue referring to left-hand operand.
- `int* j = x = y`, this is erroneous because of invalid types of the operands.

But,

- `int* j = &(x = y)` :

  works, as `x = y` returns l-value so this boils down to `int *j = &x` (value of x is y)

  and similarly, this `int& j = x = y` also works

**Additional links:**

For conditional expressions: [Return type of '?:' (ternary conditional operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator)