# Function return creates temporary despite using const references

Tags: c++

I have a function, that returns a reference to an entry in a `std::vector` or a null object. I bind this object to a `const &` expecting it to point to the original object in the vector:

```
inline MyClass const & getSomeClassObject( char const * const strName ) const
{
  static MyClass nullObj;
  for ( auto const & entry : m_myClassObjectsVector )
  {
     if ( entry.name == strName ) return entry;
  }

  return nullObj;
}
```

And this is how the function is called:

```
MyClass const & myReference = !someOtherObject.isValid() ? m_SomeMemberObject->getSomeClassObject( strName ) : MyClass();
```

However adding a copy constructor to `MyClass` showed that the object is copied on return which causes problems because the temporary lives shorter than `m_SomeMemberObject`.

Apparently the conditional operator has something to do with it as removing it will eliminate the copy.

But can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Something possible wrong is with m_myClassObjectsVector.

Comment: The returned type of condition operator is same for both sides. I presume the rules mandate the returned type to be `MyClass` and not a reference to it as otherwise on false condition the default constructed instance would get destroyed by the end the of the line - and const reference returned would be faulty.

Comment: `? :` returns a prvalue in this case (because the last operand is prvalue), forcing the second operand to be copied (to form a prvalue). Unsure how to fix this.

Comment: adding a copy constructor has some implicit actions associated with it.  also did you turn on optimizations?  what happens when you explicitly work with pointers?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Maybe like `? m_SomeMemberObject->getSomeClassObject( strName ) : m_SomeMemberObject->getNullClassObject();`

Comment: @S.M. Yes, that would work. Though I have a distaste for null singletons.

Comment: `... : static_cast<const MyClass&>(MyClass());` A ternary operator (expressed in very sloppy terms) attempts to find a type to which both alternative operands can be converted. It cannot make an L-value out of an R-value, but it can do the opposite. This question is, to some extent, [a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator). The answers contain a detailed explanation of the phenomenon. So your L-value operand, if picked by the condition, must become an R-value and making a copy is a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the possible solution

```
inline MyClass const & getNullClassObject() const
{
  static MyClass nullObj;
  return nullObj;
}

inline MyClass const & getSomeClassObject( char const * const strName ) const
{
  for ( auto const & entry : m_myClassObjectsVector )
  {
     if ( entry.name == strName ) return entry;
  }

  return getNullClassObject();
}

MyClass const & myReference = !someOtherObject.isValid() ? m_SomeMemberObject->getSomeClassObject( strName ) : m_SomeMemberObject->getNullClassObject();
```

Both parts of the ? expression now return const lvalue references and no copy for getting pure rvalue performed.

Comment: Now that you mention it: would replacing : MyClass();  by a static object also be formally correct?

Comment: Can you name me the point in the standard where this rule that the last two operands are harmonized stands?

Comment: [Conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `getSomeClassObject()` method returns the same type of object that the calling code wants to use when the `strName` is not found, I would probably just apply the `?:` operator to the parameter of the method call, rather than using it to decide whether to call the method at all, eg:

```cpp
inline MyClass const & getSomeClassObject( char const * const strName ) const
{
    static MyClass nullObj;
    if (strName) {
        for ( auto const & entry : m_myClassObjectsVector ) {
            if ( strcmp(entry.name, strName) == 0 ) return entry;
        }
    }
    return nullObj;
}
```

```
MyClass const & myReference = m_SomeMemberObject->getSomeClassObject( !someOtherObject.isValid() ? strName : nullptr );
```