# Understanding the return statement (analogRead(A1) > 500 ? (1<<1) : 0)

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino project for multiple switches to be turned on in a sequence (4,3,1,2).
I've been able to find a code that would work but I am struggling to understand what is happening.

Its a return function  that makes sense, however the "?" and ":0" is where I get lost

Here is the code

```
uint8_t readSwitches()
{
  return (analogRead(A1) > 500 ? (1<<1) : 0)
       | (analogRead(A2) > 500 ? (1<<2) : 0)
       | (analogRead(A3) > 500 ? (1<<3) : 0)
       | (analogRead(A4) > 500 ? (1<<4) : 0);
}
```

Can someone explain what is happening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return type of '?:' (ternary conditional operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535226/return-type-of-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 1):

it's a so called `ternary operator`
and is of the form `A ? B : C` and is a shortened `if-else`

`If(A)`
then `B`
else  `C`

https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html

So what this `return` statement does is

checking if the `Ax` variables are `> 500`and if they are, setting a certain bit and bitwise `OR` them together

Comment: Checking if Ax variables are > 500 ...

Comment: ... if they are, each operator returns 2, 4, 8, and 16 respectively, 0 otherwise ...